# Obtain a list of elements from a JSON array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops, for-loop

This is how I handle the request from the server and the array I get as a result:

```
       $result = json_decode($request->response)->result;
       $response = array('status' => 0, 'rpcresult' => $result);
       echo json_encode($response);

{"status":0,"rpcresult":[
{"key":"10","pcode":"30001"},
{"key":"11","pcode":"30002"},
{"key":"12","pcode":"30003"},
{"key":"13","pcode":"30004"},
{"key":"14","pcode":"30005"}]}
```

This is my first attempt at getting a list of all **pcode** elements:

```
 success: function(response) {
 for (i= 0;i < response.rpcresult.length;i++){
 if (response.status == 0) {
 msg = '<h2>'+response.rpcresult[i].pcode+'</h2>';
 }
 else
 msg = 'ERROR (' + response.error + ')';
 $("#PopupBody").html(msg);
 $("#ModalPopup").modal('show');  
 }
 }
```

The problem with this is that it returns only the last pcode element (30005) and I'm not really sure why.

Comment: I think this might work: `msg = msg + '<h2>'+response.rpcresult[i].pcode+'</h2>';`. In case msg has not been create before, create it before the api call. It will paste the already made messages in front of the new one. Making some sort of a list. Currently you are just replacing the msg variable each time the for loop triggers

Comment: Why? Because you are overwriting the value of `msg` with a new one each time, instead of _appending to_ the already existing value.

Comment: That's probably it, how do I do this in php? Is there a function or something?

Answer (score 0):

```
   $stringajson="{"status":0,"rpcresult":[
                    {"key":"10","pcode":"30001"},{"key":"11","pcode":"30002"}, 
                    {"key":"12","pcode":"30003"},{"key":"13","pcode":"30004"},
                    {"key":"14","pcode":"30005"}]}";

  $myapplication = array();
  $myapplication = json_decode($resp, true);
  $orders=array();
  $orders=$myapplication["rpcresult"];
  for($q=0; $q<count($orders);$q++)
  {
    echo "<h2>".$orders[$q]["pcode"]."</h2>";
  }
```

Comment: This could work but the content of the array might vary, I need something more flexible. Anyway thanks for your answer